# isNaN not working JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, integer, nan, parseint

I’m having trouble with the isNaN function is JavaScript. I have a variable, trc, which I know is not a number, but I want my code to be able to tell. Unfortunately, isNaN isn’t detecting that it’s not a number, yet when I use an alert to show the value of the variable, it is indeed not a number.

```js
trc = parseInt(getCookie("trc"));
cnn = parseInt(getCookie("cnn"));
klove = parseInt(getCookie("klove"));
if (isNaN(trc)) {
  trc = 0;
}
if (getCookie("trc") == undefined) {
  trc = 0;
} else {
  trc = parseInt(getCookie("trc"));
}
alert(trc);
```

BTW, I have a separate function, getCookie(), that I made myself to get the value of a cookie.

Comment: `parseInt` isn't executing as getCookie is undefined.

Comment: The `isNaN()` function means, "is the parameter the `NaN` value?" not "is the parameter not a number".

Comment: Also note that it's possible to get to that `alert()` after setting `trc` to the cookie value without an intermediate `isNaN()` test. If the cookie value is not `undefined`, then the second `if` statement will set `trc` to the result of passing the cookie value to `parseInt()`, which may return `NaN`.

Comment: You'll have to provide some sample data with which it fails. The function is probably working just fine as it's supposed to, you simply have the wrong expectations for your input.

Comment: Thanks, decease. You and Kamil are right. I fixed it by checking if trc > -1, since the way my program runs it will always be 0 or greater. Of course, if trc isn’t a number it won’t be less than 0. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You should check value of `trc` before.
If `trc` is `null`, then `isNaN(null)` return false.

Edit:
`parseInt` method doesn't return null value, but `trc` can be modified by external code - therefore I recommend using namespaces e.g:

```
var namespace = namespace || {};
namespace.trc = .....
```

Comment: I test for null and it still gives me NaN.